# Using both personal mail server and external service with one domain

Tags: domain-name-system, email, email-server, mandrill

I use my personal mail server for mails that go out of my app (transactional emails only), and for employees company mail inbox. Now I would like to send out some newsletter for the first time in bulk numbers (to my existing customers of course, yes GDPR :)). I would like to use one of services for that (mailgun, mandrill, etc, - havent decided yet). Is it possible to use same domain for both private mail server and for external service to send mails on your behalf, without having to sacrifice private server DNS settings?

**Decision explanation:**

My private server is doing a great job, getting the top scores with anti spam services, but i want to keep it small, dont want to take my chances ruining my spam reputation making some mistakes when playing with big numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use the same domain for your own server and mailing campaigns  sent by a third party.

Technically : Typically the third party will require that you add  an additional DKIM key for them in your domains DNS zone and you’ll need to include one or more SPF records for their infrastructure authorizing them to send mail on your behalf.

Comment: The problem with using a 3rd party is "who have they made mad in the past"  - your mail's reputation is tied to them, and their customers.  I would split off a sub-domain (`lists.example.com`) and set up your own listserv  or similar software.  Use a VPS, image it, save your image locally, and kill the machine after your mail has gone.  Need to send mail again later? Spin up a VM, restore your configured image, and send away...

Answer (score 0):

HBruijn's answer is correct. You can.
On the other hand, if you're worried about reputation, I'd go with a subdomain.

Reputation is mostly built on domain name and if DKIM signing is applied, on the domain you are signing with.

I'd go with a tool that allows you to DKIM sign your emails with a subdomain of your top-level domain, but still use a header.FROM which shows your top-level domain.

At the same time many tools include bounce-handling and options to unsubscribe via a link or tap into large ESPs feedback loops, to unsubscribe customers that marked your BULK emails as SPAM. Therefor you should be able to also set the Return-Path address (a.k.a. smtp.mailfrom or Envelope From or Bounce Address) to use a subdomain.

Also, you  might want to consider that large ESPs will throttle your email or even treat it as SPAM when suddenly sending large amounts from a new IP address (for your domain). You might want to "warm-up" your new IP, to build some reputation.

If you want to apply above and also have a DMARC record set up? Make sure that you set the alignment for SPF (aspf=r) and DKIM (adkim=r) to "relaxed", which it is by default. It will let you authenticate with a different domain than your Header.From domain, as long as it shares the same Organizational Domain.